# Get Keys from complex dictionary by value C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a structure like this.

```
public class particleProperty
        {
            public Point3 point_A {get; set;}
            public Point3 point_B {get; set;}
            public int hashEdge {get; set;}
            public int vertOne {get; set;}
            public int vertTwo {get; set;}
        }

public Dictionary<int, List<particleProperty>> particleEdges = new Dictionary<int, List<particleProperty>>();
```

how can i obtain Keys from dictionary by hashEdge, for example?

Comment: particleEdges.Where(x => x.Value.Any(p => p.hashEdge ... [your condition])).Select(x => x.Key)

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning. The syntax is pretty hard to learn. Good luck to you!

Comment: Note that while the code @spzvtbg will work, it is quite the opposite of what the `Dictionary` data structure is meant for - quick access by key. So if you need this access pattern regularly in your applications, re-think your data structures.

Comment: int item = particleEdges.ElementAt(i).Key;

Point3 hashPoint = particleEdges[item][j].hashEdge;  
var hashList = particleEdges
.Where(p => p.Value.Any(q => q.hashEdge == hashPoint))
.Select(r => r.Key != item)
.ToList();   //How to exclude self key from search lisе?